# Angular Forms - how to edit (patch) an existing record by its ID

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to patch an existing record (edit component). This is my `edit.ts` file:

```
 this.signupform=this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['',Validators.required],
      lastName: ['',Validators.required],
      birthDate: ['',Validators.required],
      adharNo: ['',Validators.required],
      visitingDate: ['',Validators.required],
      picture: ['',Validators.required],
      flatblock: ['',Validators.required],
      flatno: ['',Validators.required],
      phoneNo: ['',Validators.required],
      bikeNo: ['',Validators.required]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
 this.signupform.patchValue({
      firstName: 'fname',
      lastName: 'lname'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-fill the form with the data of my existing record:

```
this.alimentForm.setValue({
    name: alimToEdit.name,
    icon: alimToEdit.iconicFontName,
    category: alimToEdit.category,
    storedDate: alimToEdit.storedDate,
    expirationDate: alimToEdit.expirationDate,
    quantityValue: alimToEdit.quantity,
    quantityUnit: alimToEdit.quantityUnit,
    id: alimToEdit.id
});
```

And then in the register function I would extract the data from the form like this for example:

```
let formVal = this.alimentForm.value;
            let alimFromForm: Aliment = new Aliment({
                name: formVal.name
                , category: formVal.category
                , iconicFontName: formVal.icon
                , quantity: formVal.quantityValue
                , quantityUnit: formVal.quantityUnit
                , storedDate: formVal.storedDate
                , expirationDate: formVal.expirationDate
            });
```